# how to detect a paragraph from a Text string and make it clickable in android studio?

Tags: android

how to detect a paragraph from a Text string and make it clickable ??????
I am working on android . I can detect Character, word and Sentence. I can also detect paragraph by "string.split()" function. But I am unable to make the paragraph clickable.

Comment: Can you please add code or explain more about output?